# Connecting firebase to my TextField/Material Login page code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am quite new to app development and very new to Firebase, and I am having a difficult time finding sources online that caters to the code I have written specifically. I have already edited the needed pages (like the pubsepc file, build.gradle file, etc.) I am having trouble editing my actual code. For my login page, I used multiple TextFields and Material buttons. This code is part of the class _HomePageState extends State part of the code.

Could anyone help me figure out a technique or give me a hint to connect firebase with this? I have seen other examples online, but none use specifically TextField like my code. Many have additional functions and I am unsure if I needed them. I would prefer to use TextField but is using TextField even possible? Thank you.

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final email = TextField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Email",
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final password = TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Password",
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final loginButon = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text("Login",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: style.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I've removed android-studio and xcode tags from this, as the question isn't directly referencing either of those products.  Those tags should be used only for questions that have something specific to do with those pieces of software. They don't apply if you're simply using those tools to build your app.

Comment: My apologies, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this what you can do, this code is for log in button
userEmail and userPassword are strings that you get from both text fields

```
onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: userEmail, password: userPassword);
                      print(result.user.email : userEmail);//#debug statement
                      setState(() {});
                    //navigator push here, to go to next page, if login is successfull
                    } catch (e) {
                      print('error during login is $e'); // #debug
                    }
                  },
```

in the init state you can use this function to check if someone is logged in or not, this for next time when user launches the app, they will be automatically logged in

```
@override
  void initState() {
    isUserLoggedIn();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() async {
    var x = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (x != null) {
      // code to be execute if someone is already logged in, take him to next page
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow! It worked very nicely, thank you so much, you helped a lot! I was going around in circles trying to figure it out :)